# document.getElementById not working before a long function?

Tags: javascript

My problem is that i would like to change a style of a html element and after that call a function. This is my function i call and the log with the element:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('hotLoader'));
console.log(document.getElementById('hotLoader').style);
console.log(document.getElementById('hotLoader').style.display);
self.onTableClick(e, coord, hot, ifcClass);
```

Now right when i call it this is the Output:

[image]

You cann see that the first log is blank. After the `onTableClick()` function ended, the first log updates and i get this output:

[image]

Now you can see the marked red log is now update.

The problem I have is that **I need the first log to appear before the function starts**. I tried to solve that problem for so long now and cant find anything.

Comment: Why do you need to see the result of a `console.log` operation before the long function runs? Why not just use the debugger built into the browser to look directly at the style object?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i need to actually change a attribute of the element, but i cant do that  since i dont get the element. The log shows exactly what my problem is. Any idea why?

Comment: Please include any relevant and necessary textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To let the browser repaint (including the console, in many browsers), you need to allow the current JavaScript task (job) to complete, and then have the long-running function happen in a subsequent task/job. THe classic way to do that is to use `setTimeout` with a delay of 0.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('hotLoader'));
console.log(document.getElementById('hotLoader').style);
console.log(document.getElementById('hotLoader').style.display);
setTimeout(() => {
    self.onTableClick(e, coord, hot, ifcClass);
}, 0);
```

Firefox used to need a longer delay than that (sometimes 60ms or more), but I don't think modern versions of it do.

Comment: Yes Perfect! Thank you very much. :)